# Hypothesis testing for non-randomly sampled data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, multiple-comparisons

I have a set of data points which are a number of parameters and a discrete measure. The data is bifurcated (using decision tree regression on the parameters) to select a sample which has the highest mean. I want to run some hypothesis test on this to determine whether the selected sample is actually a population from a different distribution or if it is simply the tail end of a distribution describing all of the data.

Since the sample is not randomly selected I don't think something like a t-test would be correct to use, but not quite sure if there exists something that is suitable here. The number of possible splits somehow needs to be taken into account as well, but not sure if running some multiple hypothesis correction is enough either. What methods exist for this? Perhaps there is some Bayesian approach?